# How to adjust labels of loadings in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I can't get the labels to go at the end of the arrows instead of the base:
[image]

here is the exact code I used:

```
ggplot <- ggplot(data=sep_total_raw_data, aes(x=pc1t, y=pc2t))+geom_point(alpha=0.8, size=1,aes(colour=Data_Type, shape=Data_Type))+xlab("PC1 (53.83%)")+ylab("PC2 (26.3%)")+guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Data_Type"))+geom_mark_hull(concavity=5, expand=0, radius=0, aes(fill=Data_Type))+theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+geom_text(aes(label=Code, fontface="bold", colour=Data_Type))

ggplot + geom_segment(data = PCA_loadings, aes(x=0, y=0, xend=PC1*4.6, yend=PC2*4.6), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc")), alpha=1)+ geom_text(data=PCA_loadings, mapping = aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, label=rownames(PCA_loadings)), hjust=1, vjust=-0.2)
```

Here is the reproducible code:

```
ggplot <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width))+geom_point(alpha=0.8, size=1,aes(colour=Species, shape=Species))+xlab("Petal Length")+ylab("Petal Width")+guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Species"))+geom_mark_hull(concavity=5, expand=0, radius=0, aes(fill=Species))+theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+geom_text(aes(label=Species, fontface="bold", colour=Species))
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the loadings labels to sit at the end of the arrows?

Comment: The reproducible example using the iris data set doesn't have any arrows or text included. To put the text at the end of the arrows, the `x` and `y` values for the text should match the `xend` and `yend` values for the arrows. You have e.g. `x = PC1` for text but `xend = PC1 * 4.6` for the arrows - they should be the same. PS it's good practice to avoid defining variables with the same name as functions you are using.

Comment: @nrennie that worked, thank you so much!